# Call a server side method when a textbox value is programatically changed by javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, onchange

I have a textbox,

```
<input type="text" id="hoverChange" runat="server" onchange="hoverAction"/>
```

I have the below method defined in the server side code,

```
protected void hoverAction(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sectionName=hoverChange.Value;
    if (sectionName != "") sectionHoverUserControl.displayHoverContent(sectionName);
}
```

I need the above method to be executed when I programatically set some value to the textbox. I tried to do the below, But neither fired the onchange event,

```
document.getElementById('<%= hoverChange.ClientID %>').value = "some_text";
```

or

```
$('#<%= hoverChange.ClientID %>').val("some_text");
```

I would appreciate your help!
Thanks,
Harish

Answer (score 1):

The browser does not fire "change" events when you update the value of an input programmatically. You can, with jQuery, do this:

```
$('#<%= hoverChange.ClientID %>').val("some_text").change();
```

to trigger the event yourself. (You can do it without jQuery, but it's a bit more involved.)

Comment: I realize the post isn't tagged `jQuery`, but it was used in the body of the question so I call fair :-)

Answer (score 0):

use keyup event to fire the necessary code..